# How to Save a Generic Measurement<Unit> in Core Data?

Tags: swift, generics, core-data

How does one save and retrieve a generic Measurement in Core Data?

What I'm looking to do is save either a `Measurement<UnitMass>` or a `Measurement<UnitVolume>`.

As can be seen in the image below CoreData is set to accept a Generic `Measurement<Unit>`

[image: Generic Measurement in Core Data]

However I'm getting an error when I go to set the value of the measure. Saying that I'm not allowed to do this. I thought the purpose of generics was to support uses like this.

What am i missing?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error about mismatched types isn't the important part here. The real problem is that transformable attributes only work with classes that conform to `NSCoding` or for which you've written your own custom value transformer. Since `Measurement` is not a class and does not conform to `NSCoding`, you can't use it with a transformable attribute.

Your options are

1. Don't save the `Measurement`, save its values, and convert to/from the `Measurement` when saving/reading property values.
2. Write your own custom subclass of `ValueTransformer` that will convert between `Measurement` and `Data`.

I'd go with #1. You could add convenience methods on your managed object subclass to handle the conversion.

**Update**: Using your `Measurement<UnitMass>` case, I'd do something like:

- Give the attribute a `Double` property named `massValue`.
- Give the attribute a transformable property named `massUnit` with custom class `UnitMass` (see below).
- Save values with something like this:

  ```
  let servingMeasure = Measurement<UnitMass>(value:500, unit:.grams)
  myObject.massValue = servingMeasure.value
  myObject.massUnit = servingMeasure.unit
  ```
- Retrieve values with something like:

  ```
  if let unit = myObject.massUnit {
      let value = myObject.massValue
      let measurement = Measurement<UnitMass>(value:value, unit:unit)
      print("Measurement: \(measurement)")
  }
  ```

This is how the `massUnit` property is configured:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom, 

I just tested saving Measurement<UnitMass> to Core Data and it crashed Xcode twice in a row, so looks like you're right about being unable to save it in Core Data.

How would you save the unit value from measurement? I've tried saving a transformable with the Custom Class set to UnitMass but Xcode crashes when i save the context. Perhaps i need a value transformer?

I suppose you could save "unit" as Strings (grams, kg, oz) but i'm looking for a solution that will support localization of units.

Comment: Added much more detail.

Comment: Hey Tom, Great answer. I just made a similar property with UnitTemperature. However I'm getting this in the log: `[general] 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release`. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, Measurement does adopt the code able protocol, and therefore it can be saved in Core Data through a transformable attribute.

The error that you got is actually pretty clear. You can't save a specific Measurement type `Measurement<UnitMass>` to the generic type `Measurement<Unit>` in Core Data. You can't do it in the main code, either. The fix is simple, for each attribute specify the specific type for that attribute as the Custom Class.