# Transformable and NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, transformable

I'm trying to save a Measurement to a Core Data transformable property. Basically, what's in this answer, only a different unit: [How to Save a Generic Measurement<Unit> in Core Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522897/how-to-save-a-generic-measurementunit-in-core-data)

Everything works, however I'm getting this message in the log:
`[general] 'NSKeyedUnarchiveFromData' should not be used to for un-archiving and will be removed in a future release`

I'm not sure how to fix this. Or what exactly it means. This is my first time working with a transformable Core Data property.

Thanks

---

Edit:

I made a new class:

```
import Foundation

@objc(UnitTemperatureValueTransformer)
final class UnitTemperatureValueTransformer: NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer {
    static let name = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: String(describing: UnitTemperatureValueTransformer.self))
    override static var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass] {
        return [UnitTemperature.self]
    }
    
    public static func register() {
        let transformer = UnitTemperatureValueTransformer()
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: name)
    }
}
```

And then I set the transformer value for the Core Data object to: `UnitTemperatureValueTransformer`.

Is that all that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning appears because apple will remove it in future release because it's not secure by default. Here is [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/107533) on Apple forum.
You should use [NSSecureUnarchiveFromData](https://www.kairadiagne.com/2020/01/13/nssecurecoding-and-transformable-properties-in-core-data.html) instead of that.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question with what I've done. It seems to be working, but can you double check it?

Comment: For me it looks ok.

Comment: @StonedStudio if my answer was helpful, please accept the answer or vote up

Comment: Thanks for double checking it. Seems strange it’s that easy to do. But I’m not complaining