# Using Swift's Measurement() type convert String into UnitType

Tags: swift, core-data, units-of-measurement

I am internationalizing my app to accept and return measurements in any system. Because of this I won't be able to use a hard coded `UnitType` when creating a `Measurement(value: value, unit: unit)` (user chooses unit type from a picker). I'm storing the user entered values into Core Date by separately storing the value as a Double and the UnitType as a String. for example:

```
person.height = 190.0
person.heightUnit = "UnitLength.centimeters"
```

If I were to hard code the UnitType as UnitLength.centimeters, as below:

```
let personHeight = 190.0

let height = Measurement(value: personHeight, unit: UnitLength.centimeters)

Text("Height = \(height.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .personHeight).locale(Locale(identifier: "en-US"))))")
```

It returns the expected "Height = 6 ft, 2.8 in"

If I then try to construct a UnitType from the value in person.heightUnit as in the following:

```
let personHeight = 190.0
let personHeightUnit = "UnitLength.centimeters"

let unit = UnitLength(symbol: personHeightUnit)
let height = Measurement(value: personHeight, unit: unit)
Text("Height = \(height.formatted(.measurement(width: .abbreviated, usage: .personHeight).locale(Locale(identifier: "en-US"))))")
```

This returns "Height = 0 in"

How do I convert the String "UnitLength.centimeters" as stored in CoreData into a type Unit that works with Measurement?

Comment: You should be able to store the entire `Measurement` in CoreData, as a `Transformable`. It conforms to `NSCoding`, after all. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/67113930/5133585

Comment: OK, that's different from what I read in another post where it was stated that:
"The real problem is that transformable attributes only work with classes that conform to NSCoding or for which you've written your own custom value transformer. Since Measurement is not a class and does not conform to NSCoding, you can't use it with a transformable attribute." That was from 2018 though, so maybe there's been a change to Measurement since then?

Comment: Not sure what that was talking about. `Measurment` *does*  conform to `NSCoding`. How about actually *trying*?

Comment: @Sweeper, but I still need to construct a Unit variable in order to create the Measurement in the first place. I can pass `value` in as a variable. there must be a way to pass `unit` in as well. Xcode wanted to fix my error using `UnitLength(symbol: String)` which is why I tried that, but it clearly didn't work as I thought it should.

Comment: save the symbol instead and you can use the symbol with a function/subscript that you create to get the Swift provided unit instead of an empty unit, this is a known behavior.

Comment: I don't think you need to save the type of the value.  localised values are an input and output problem, not a storage problem. `Measurement` can take care of conversion for you.  Always use the SI units when saving. For example, a height is always in cm.  Once you have recreated the `Measurement`  you can then decide to display it as inches